# Numberpad Error

Tags: 3d-view

I recently downloaded Blender 3.0 and found that my side views were not accurately placed when I would use the number pad to change perspectives. They were be off a little bit and not perfect. Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: You should explain a bit more, what numbers have you pressed and show some screenshots so that we can understand how your views are "off". Right now, it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem from your post.

Comment: Hi :). There's a slight difference when using a Perspective vs Ortographic view. Could that be it?

Comment: Press 5 on numpad, as Jachym said.

Comment: On Blender 2.8+ pressing `1`, `3`, or `7` switch automatically to Orthographic view but since he doesn't say exactly what numbers he pressed..

Comment: hm on a new blend file it seems to be working maybe i was pressing 2 on the number pad instead of 3. haha thanks for the responses guys.